# Como posso checar se um elemento de uma lista que corresponde ao valor de um dicionário está relacionado com a chave?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Código:

```
entrada = ''
dici_presentes = {}
listavalores = []
while entrada != 'FIM':
    casos = int(input())
    for i in range(casos):
        nome_presente = input().split()
        c = nome_presente[0]
        v = nome_presente[1:]
        dici_presentes[c] = v
    print(dici_presentes)
    entrada = input()
```

**Exemplo de entrada:**

```
5
iara mochila estojo lapis
adelar sapato camisa carteira
jessica agenda bolsa brincos
jocelina xicara meias perfume
elaine sandalia sapatilha camiseta
iara mochila (irá retornar verdadeiro)
iara sabonete (irá retornar falso)
FIM
```

**Saída:**

```
Verdadeiro
Falso
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, a leitura das 5 entradas não deve ser feita dentro do `while`, pois você já sabe que serão 5 linhas. O `while` é só depois, para ler os casos em que você irá verificar se o presente existe ou não para cada pessoa.

Para ler os nomes e os respectivos presentes, você pode usar a atribuição múltipla juntamente com o [*unpacking*](http://%5B*unpacking*%5D(https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)):

```
nome, *presentes = input().split()
```

Assim, se a linha for, por exemplo, `iara mochila estojo lapis`, o `nome` será `iara` e `presentes` será uma lista contendo 3 elementos: as strings `'mochila'`, `'estojo'` e `'lapis'`. Claro que da forma que você fez também funciona, só quis mostrar outra alternativa.

Depois, basta guardar isso no dicionário, sendo que o `nome` é a chave e `presentes`, o respectivo valor:

```
dici_presentes = {}
casos = int(input())
for i in range(casos):
    nome, *presentes = input().split()
    dici_presentes[nome] = presentes

while True: # loop "infinito"
    entrada = input()
    if entrada == 'FIM':
        break
    else:
        nome, presente = entrada.split()
        print(presente in dici_presentes[nome])
```

Depois, eu começo a ler os casos de teste. Se for "FIM", eu interrompo o `while` com `break`. Senão, eu faço o `split`, pegando o nome e o presente. E por fim, eu uso `in` para verificar se o `presente` está na lista correspondente ao `nome`.

O código acima imprime `True` e `False`, mas se quiser trocar o texto, basta fazer:

```
while True:
    entrada = input()
    if entrada == 'FIM':
        break
    else:
        nome, presente = entrada.split()
        if presente in dici_presentes[nome]:
            print('Verdadeiro')
        else:
            print('Falso')
```

---

Um detalhe é que o código acima não verifica se o nome realmente é uma chave do dicionário (ele sempre assume que é). Se tiver que verificar esses casos também, basta trocar a condição para:

```
if nome in dici_presentes and presente in dici_presentes[nome]:
    print('Verdadeiro')
else:
    print('Falso')
```

Ou seja, primeiro vejo se `nome` é uma chave, e só depois vejo se o `presente` está na respectiva lista.

Outra forma é:

```
if presente in dici_presentes.get(nome, []):
    print('Verdadeiro')
else:
    print('Falso')
```

O `get` tenta obter o valor da chave indicada por `nome`, e caso não encontre, retorna `[]` (uma lista vazia). Ou seja, se o `nome` não for uma chave do dicionário, o `presente` não será encontrado, já que a lista vazia não possui nenhum elemento e por isso nenhum `presente` estará nela.

Comment: Muito obrigado, aprendi muita coisa em apenas um código.